# Ubuntu 14.04 Sound does not work until opening Sound Settings menu

Tags: 14.04, sound

Possible duplicate of: ["Master" volume control not controlling output volume level](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697793/master-volume-control-not-controlling-output-volume-level)

After the computer falls asleep, sound won't work until I open the Sound Settings menu.

If I open this via terminal using gnome-control-center sound, the process runs, but then a second process seems to start up and displays the error message

```
(unity-control-center:5161): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: Unable to find stream for bar '(null)'

(unity-control-center:5161): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: active_output_update - couldn't find a stream from the supposed active output
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: What's your setup? A 'desktop' computer plugged into a Monitor with Monitor Speakers too, or separate speakers or a laptop? Laptop with dual monitor setup?

Comment: Desktop computer, with headphones plugged in (two monitors if that's relevant). The selected output needs to be HDMI / Display Output

Comment: Just wondering whether when it wakes from sleep it's changing the output source to what it thinks is 'default' rather than the HDMI output. When you open the Sound Settings do you have to select the output source to get the sound to work again or does opening the Sound Settings mean that the sound just 'kicks in'?

Comment: All I have to do is open Sound Settings for it to kick in. I can open it up with `gnome-control-center sound` instead of through the GUI, but it also gives those error messages above (which prevents me from running other commands like `wmctrl` to subsequently close it)

Comment: Hmm. That's odd behaviour. I wouldn't have thought that just opening the sound settings would 're-enable' the sound, but that seems to be the case here. I don't think I'm going to be much help but just trying to narrow down where the problem might lie so that someone else will recognise what's going wrong and have some ideas how to fix it. You mention gnome-control-center - did you install that additionally or have you installed the gnome-desktop as well?

Comment: Ahaha I agree it's definitely odd. I can't remember if I installed gnome-control-center, but I'm pretty sure I didn't (at least the GUI was already there). I'm installing `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` now to see if that helps things.

Comment: Yes odd, but the same thing is happening to me as well. Not gnome, unity. Also dual monitor setup